# is it possible to generate create index sql in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a table have many index, now I want to move the index to another table. Is it possible to auto generate the index create sql using SQL command? so I do not need to generate index by myself(generate create index sql by hande).

Comment: Use the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz\G` and then copy and paste your table structure...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name;`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-show-indexes/) to script the list of indexes on that table.